# python django return different variables

Tags: python, django, templates

I'm looking for a way to return `True` or a string, and later use that info to show something or not. Here is my code:

```
def time_remaining(self):
    timer = self.timer
    now = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(tzinfo=utc)
    if timer < now:
        return True
    else:
        #Returns a timedelta in string
        return game_logic.timedelta_format(timer - now)
```

Then later on I use:

```
if time_remaining():
    possible = True
else:
    possible = False

return render(request, 'training.html',{'possible': possible})
```

and finally in my template:

```
{% if possible %}
    <some html>
{% else %}
    <different html>
{% endif %}
```

Somehow I always end up at the  even if the time_remaining returns the string instead of True

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python non-empty strings also evaluate as `True`:

```
>>> bool('foo')
True
>>> bool('')
False
```

So no matter what your `time_remaining` function returns, it will always be evaluated as `True` in your `if` statement.

You probably want to use something like:

```
time_remaining() == True
```

Or perhaps even have `time_remaining` return `False` or `None` if there is no time left (especially if you are only going to use the output of `time_remaining` in your `if` statement).

Answer (score 0):

```
time_remaining() == True:
```

Seems that does the trick :) Figured it always returns something
Some explanation what exactly is going on would be still apreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your `time_remaining` function always returns a value that evaluates to `True` in the `if` statement. So `possible` will always be `True`.

Add some extra logic in your second code block to do the behaviour you expect, such as testing the value of the time delta.

Answer (score 0):

Function outputs should be of the same type, with the special value 'None' to tell an empty output (although I cannot find any reference for this statement...).

So, you should do:

```
if timer < now:
    return game_logic.timedelta_format(empty_timedelta) 
else:
    #Returns a timedelta in string
    return game_logic.timedelta_format(timer - now)
```

or:

```
time_limit = min(timer, now) #if 'min' applies
return game_logic.timedelta_format(timer - time_limit )
```

or:

```
if timer < now:
    return None
else:
    #Returns a timedelta in string
    return game_logic.timedelta_format(timer - now)
```

or return a couple of values: the first tells the kind of result, the second is the actual result

```
if timer < now:
    return (True, None)
else:
    #Returns a timedelta in string
    return (False, game_logic.timedelta_format(timer - now))
```